# Keeping parts of an SVG at fixed size

Tags: javascript, svg

Essentially I needed to make the center "cut-out" keep a fixed shape and size regardless of vector scale. Is there a way to achieve this?

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="none" style="fill-rule:evenodd;" viewBox="0 0 2802 2657">
 <path d="M290 4c-95,733 -191,1466 -286,2200 760,150 1520,300 2279,450 172,-223 343,-446 515,-669 -114,-572 -229,-1144 -343,-1716 -722,-88 -1444,-176 -2165,-264zm696 1027c-103,111 -205,222 -308,333 94,111 188,222 282,333 342,-205 684,-410 1026,-616 -333,-17 -667,-34 -1000,-51z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: write some javascript to change the object's size each time the drawing as a whole is resized.

Answer (score 3):

So I managed to do something after some editing to your SVG.

To achieve what you're asking you'll need to use / have : 
 - the SVG mask attribute
 - A very large shape for the mask ( as much large as the max scale you want to use on the visible shape )
 - The shape that you want to resize
 - Resize the shape with transforms

Your SVG should looks like the following

```
<svg>
    <defs>
       <mask id="theMask">
          <path fill="#ffffff" d=""/>
       </mask>
    </defs>
    <g mask="url(#theMask)">
        <path fill="#ffffff" id="shapetoresize" d=""/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

[image]

I posted a pen as a "Proof of concept"
Feel free to fork it and use it to achieve what you're trying to do.
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/alaricweb/pen/b0e353f61a370cb89b6e8f9e1bf9f2ca)

note: as pointed out by @thioutp , The JS is only for demo purposes, you don't need GSAP to achieve this.

Comment: Wow really nice job ! Smart solution, but you seem's to be using a custom library ?

Comment: Hi @thiout_p, Thanks for pointing this out. The library I'm using is only for demo purposes. It's not required for the solution to work.

Comment: It's good SO practise to post your entire code in an embedded answer rather than linking.

Comment: Thank you @Michael Mullany I'll try to integrate my code more often within the answer.

Comment: Nice idea.. but this only works because of css transform and won't make any difference with preserveAspectRatio="none" or is there a way to make only '#largeshape' scale to fit its parent?

Comment: I'm not sure I totally understand, but indeed I think that my solution require the use of transform.